# Does paying down debt in an S Corp decrease profitability?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, debt, s-corporation

Long story short - I'm a participating shareholder of a small S Corp that has debt.

At the end of the year, since it's an S Corp, the profits/losses are passed down to the shareholders to be reported on our personal tax returns.

In the interest of reducing our personal tax obligation, the suggestion was made to pay down some of our debt to reduce our profitability. Someone else pointed out that this isn't how it works - paying down debt won't decrease profitability for tax purposes.

Is this, indeed, true? Is there a good resource to check out for an overview of this concept?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Someone else pointed out that this isn't how it works - paying down debt won't decrease profitability for tax purposes.

"Someone else" is correct. Principal payments on debt are not tax deductible; only the interest on debt is a tax deductible expense. From an accounting standpoint this intuitively makes sense: when you take out a loan, the business bank account is credited, and the new loan account is debited. That money is not considered income and is not taxable. Similarly, when you move money back from the bank account into the loan account (paying off principal), the reverse is true, and the payment is not an expense.

A good example of this is when the loan is a line of credit. It's common to move money out of the LOC into the bank account to cover payroll for a few days, and then move it back after a customer check clears. This way only a few days of interest is paid (which is deductible), but of course the full amount of money moved is not.

Comment: Awesome; thank you! I imagine this concept is incredibly basic to you, but it's reassuring to have confirmation from someone who has no vested interest in the corporation!

Comment: I would also add: don't spend money _just_ to get a tax break, and don't _not_ spend money to _keep_ a tax break (e.g. don't keep debt high just to deduct interest).

Comment: Oh the accounting nightmare it would be if we somehow how to put those loans as revenue, and any that happened to cross a barrier of a tax year were actually taxed as such, only to have it register as a loss on a future year. That would be disgusting!